# extracting hyperlinks in python.

Tags: python, function, parsing, web, browser

Im trying to make a simple web browser in python. (i'm a novice programmer and this is the first time I'm using python.)
I'm aware that i have to save my links in a list and create a function to to go to my url overtime sees that list but i have no idea how to do that. I would very much appreciate it if someone could please help me with that.

### Heading

Here's my code:   `#!/usr/bin/env python`

`import urllib`

```
url = "http://google.com"
data = urllib.urlopen(url)
tokens = data.read().split()
List=[]
for token in tokens:
if token == '<body>':
 print ''
elif token == '</body>':
print ''
#elif token[6:-2] == '<a href':
  else:
enter code here









print token,


selectedLink = raw_input('Select a link:')
```

Comment: Your code and question doesn't seem to specifically related to making a web browser, and your formatting is incorrect. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: its the first I'm asking a question here so, trying to put the whole code down was a nightmare for me. Im trying to make a simple web browser that overtime it sees the tag <a href=.... > it shows the link to the user and ask them to select an input so it can take them to that page. I've never used python before, apologies about the format

Comment: What you're looking for (identifying html tags and its properties) can be done with the python module [`beautifulsoup4`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4)